# How can I unit test my GPS/Google Maps Android application?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, junit, google-maps-android-api-2, android-testing

First of all, I am new to JUnit testing.

I've built an Android application that find's the nearest places based on the user's current location. It uses either a NETWORK or GPS Provider to obtain a location fix. After getting the fix, it retrieves the nearest locations from a remote database and places a marker on the map.

I am using Google Maps Android API v2 and I have noticed that it is not possible to test or run the maps on an emulator. Therefore, how can I unit test my application if that is the case?

Is there anyway to run tests on my device?

Answer (score 0):

Unit tests are for units.

In your code a unit would be a function, which returns a list of some model objects given geographical position and DAO. You can then mock the DAO.

Such test doesn't have to be run on the device, but can be - it's just 1e6 times slower.

For basics, start reading (a lot) about JUnit, mocking (for example with Mockito), maybe [Testing Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html), but I'd rather think of separating logic from Activities, because Activities work well and you don't have to test them really.